# Can I remint burned tokens on Uniswap?

Tags: erc-20

So if a whole LP token supply is sent to a null address and thus burned, can it be reminted as LP tokens through the LP token contract? The specific contract I am looking at, which is Uniswap's, has a mint and burn function and a transfer to address function so I assume they can be reminted by sending to the null address.

Is this correct?

Here is the source code of the contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0x21b8065d10f73ee2e260e5b47d3344d3ced7596e#code

Thank you so much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, burned LP tokens can be sending to null address for burning but Uniswap cannot remint again the same tokens. In details, when you add your liquidity to a specific pool, Uniswap mint new LP Tokens concerning your liquidity amount. When you want to retrieve your revenue from pool, you'll give LP Tokens back then Uniswap burn this tokens sending them to null address and give you your liquidity plus revenue.
Uniswap cannot remint the LP tokens from null address, but each time a liquidity provider provide liquidity to a specific pool, the DEX mint new LP tokens.